# Build "shadow" RPM database?

Tags: rpm

Let's say the ones in charge of the server are unwilling to have our department's software installed using RPM packages. Because it requires superuser rights and they are afraid it could mess up their system etc.

So we have to, instead, unpack tarballs to `/elsewhere/...`, which is a nuisance really because the process is so easy to break (wrong subdirectory, no dependency checking etc.). So I've been wondering.

There's `rpm --prefix`, which could keep the software contained (e.g. in `/elsewhere/...`).

Then there's the superuser thing... **would it be possible to build a "shadow" RPM database?**

I mean, you can `rpm --dbpath /elsewhere/rpm --initdb` and make that accessible for the non-superuser admins. Then, somehow, feed the data for the installed (system) packages into it (**how?**).

Shouldn't we then be able to `rpm --dbpath /elsewhere/rpm --prefix /elsewhere -i our_software-0.1.rpm` then without needing superuser rights?